Would imputing using the target variable then analysing correlation between variables be bad due to bias
I have mortality and nutritional data for countries, the mortality data is full for every year but the nutritional data is very limited maybe 2 or 3 years of nutritional data within a 40 year period on for most countries, maximum 10.
If I use mortality data to help impute nutrition, for then later analysing the correlation between nutrition and mortality, would it be a bad idea.
Or would it be a better idea to just impute nutrition data separately, the data is very poor quality in general with maybe about 1/3 of the countries having no nutritional data so I have no idea how to approach this.
Another method I considered was imputing by region, assuming trends between regions being similar. But the issue this ended up with was the existing data was just thrown off by whatever mean was created.
For example
if the data was
2012, -%
2013, -%
2014, 5%
2015, -%
after imputation using the entire region it ends up as something like
2012, 10%
2013, 12%
2014, 5%
2015, 16%
